# Detecting changes in a JavaScript class property?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, dom-events, prototype-programming

Assume you have this class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0
  }
  increaseCountEventually() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.count += 1
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  }
}
```

Then you create an instance of this class:

```
const foo = new Foo()
```

Then you call the `increaseCountEventually` method which will, at some random point in time, increment the value of its property `this.count`:

```
foo.increaseCountEventually()
```

So, in a few milliseconds count will increase by 1. Is there a trick to listen for changes in the `count` property of the `foo` instance? Something like an event listener, where the event would be the change of the `count` property. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
// A bit like DOM events
foo.addEventListener('property count changes', () => console.log('it changed!')) 

// Or, in other terms:
foo.listenForCountChange(() => console.log('it changed!')
```

I could use `setInterval` and check every millisecond or so to see if `count` has changed, but I'm looking for a more efficient way. I read about using a "Proxy" but not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) are meant to be used on Objects. If its okay to convert count into an object or keep an object called data with property count then you could add a proxy with a set trap

In your case however, you could modify `increaseCountEventually` to accept a function like so

```
increaseCountEventually(callback) {
    setTimeout((callback) => {
      this.count += 1,
      callback();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fairly way to monitor property updates is to store the external property under another name internally, say `_count` for `count`, and then use the external property name to set up a setter/getter pair. The [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) can take whatever action is needed when the value is updated. E.G.:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this._count = 0; // internal property name
  }
  increaseCountEventually() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.count += 1
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  }
  set count(value) { // external property name
    this._count = value;
    console.log( `count setter set _count to ${value}`);
  }
  get count() {
    return this._count;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log("foo.count = %s", foo.count);
foo.increaseCountEventually()
setTimeout( ()=>console.log("foo.count = %s", foo.count), 2000);
```

By default the `_count` property would be enumerable on class instances, and not write protected. The constructor could add `_count` as a non-enumerable property if so desired, along the lines of:

```
constructor() {
  // make _count non enumerable:

  Object.defineProperty(this, '_count', {
     value: 0,
     enumerable: false,
     writable: true
  });
}
```